# Add the on hover animation in the “sign up” with React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, onhover

I would like add the on hover animation in the “sign up”. I'm searching everywhere how do it but can't find anything.

```
<div onClick={() => toggleRegister("login")}>Sign In</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CSS `:hover` pseudo-selector:

```css
.sign-up-element {
    background-color: #f00;
    transition: background-color .3s; /* The transition property sets an animation to a specified attribute or "all" */
}

.sign-up-element:hover {
    background-color: #00f;
}
```

This approach works with any page that uses CSS.